# Pandas data frame multiplication where the data frames are of different matrix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix-multiplication, multiplication

df1 is from excel file with columns as below:

| Currency | Net Original | Net USD | COGS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USD | 1.5 | 1.2 | 2.1 |
| USD | 1.3 | 2.1 | 1.2 |
| USD | 1.1 | 2.3 | -1.1 |
| Peso Mexicano | 1.6 | 2.2 | 2.1 |

Step 1: Need to derive conversion rate column 'Conv' where 'Currency' is 'Peso Mexicano'
#Filter "Peso Mexicano" currency & take it as a separate data frame (df2)

`df2 = df1[df1['Currency']== "Peso Mexicano"]`

Step 2:
#Next use formula to get the "Conversion Rate" from df2 using formula

`df2['Conv']= (df2['Net USD']/df2['Net Original'])`

#Output 1.37

#Multiply the filtered result 'Conv' with 'COGS' column to get the desired result

```
df1['Inv'] = (df2['Conv']*df1['COGS'])*-1

display(df1)
```

However the result shows 'NaN' column 'Inv' wherever the currency is 'USD'.

Expected output:

| Currency | Net Original | Net USD | COGS | Inv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USD | 1.5 | 1.2 | 2.1 | 1.87 |
| USD | 1.3 | 2.1 | 1.2 | 0.64 |
| USD | 1.1 | 2.3 | -1.1 | -2.50 |
| Peso Mexicano | 1.6 | 2.2 | 2.1 | 1.87 |

Comment: Your numbers in the expected output don't match your description

Comment: I believe the description matches with expected output. After Step 1, new data frame df2 is created with only one row of data where currency is Peso Mexicano. Then after that in step 2, new column Conv is created in df2 using Net USD/ Net Original. Now column 'Conv' will store the value as 1.37. Then in next step, new column 'Inv' is created by multiplying (1.37* COGS value)*-1.

Comment: I agree with the 1.37, but the Inv number don't make sense to me, also COGS changes between the input and output

Comment: I see, it was in third row. I will edit that now. Thanks

Comment: How do you get -3.47? and -2.87?

Comment: Updated the 'Inv' column now

Answer (score 1):

You needed to aggregate your conv computation, even if there is only one value (I took the mean here).

Here is a working code:

```
df2 = df1[df1['Currency'] == "Peso Mexicano"]
conv = (df2['Net USD']/df2['Net Original']).mean()
df['Inv'] = conv*df['COGS']-1
```

output:

```
        Currency  Net Original  Net USD  COGS     Inv
0            USD           1.5      1.2   2.1  1.8875
1            USD           1.3      2.1   1.2  0.6500
2            USD           1.1      2.3  -1.1 -2.5125
3  Peso Mexicano           1.6      2.2   2.1  1.8875
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked.